# password protection while creating .tar file?

Tags: passwords

How to protect my application backup facility
with default password internally?
Am using to create a .tar.gz file format by making use of the 'import tarfile'.
Is there any object in it to set the password?

Answer (score 1):

Use GPG toll like that:

```
gpg -c file.tar
```

Then set the password.

To unprotect use:

```
gpg file.tar.gpg
```

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Use your choice of encryption tool on the resulting tarball.